# How to see the output produced by make install in freebsd

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, bsd-ports

When in freebsd you install any software using

```
cd /usr/ports/mysql56-server
make install
```

It produces a lot of output on the screen.

How you can read that output latter in a file.

I tried

```
cd /usr/ports/mysql56-server
make install > /home/mysql.install.log
```

BUT IT FAILED -( ........... Any Suggestion??

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
cd /usr/ports/mysql56-server
make install > /home/mysql.install.log 2>&1
```

Probably, some ouputs is printed to `stdout`, some to  `stderr`. So you can save all outputs by redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, then write `stdout` to a file.

You can also use `tee` command:

```
make install 2>&1 | tee /home/mysql.install.log
```

n.b. The `stderr` redirection is still necessary for pipes.

**@Nishan**

If you use `csh`, try this:

```
make install >& /home/mysql.install.log
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say both give `Ambiguous Output Redirect.`

Comment: Ah, maybe you use `csh`?

Comment: Great Working **UPDATED SOLUTION** +1

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `man script`. ;) Basically, you do `script somefile.txt`, and it will open a new shell where everything that happens gets written to `somefile.txt` (`exit` to quit).

Answer (score 2):

The output you are referring to is being printed to [standard error, not standard output](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection). To capture stderr, you need `2>`:

```
make install 2> /home/mysql.install.log
```

Comment: It only record error messages.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh thank you, I know. That's what I'm saying in my answer (and that's why I upvoted Gnouc's answer and will upvote yours now that Gnouc corrected it). In any case, the OP already redirected stdout and claimed it failed so presumably, they wanted stderr. Either way, please don't downvote answers unless they are actually _wrong_.

Comment: Wow, Realy sorry, i didn't read its post completly.

Comment: This did what what requested but with error but it converted my /home directory into file. **WHERE HAS GONE MY __`/home`__ DIRECTORY** -(`

Comment: @Nishan huh? Did you maybe leave a space between `/home/` and `mysql.install.log`?

Answer (score 1):

```
make install > /home/mysql.install.log 2>&1
```

0 == stdin

1 == stdout

2 == stderr

default == 1

Comment: `0` is `stdin`, `1` is `stdout`.

Comment: I'm sorry that give `Ambiguous Output Redirect.`

Comment: What's your shell?